# How to mock connection for SFTP Connection

Tags: java, mockito, sftp, jsch

My program opens sftp connection and connects to the server to get a file which is then processed.
I am writing a test case for this method, trying to mock the connection.

My actual class is:

```
public void getFile() {
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    String path = ftpurl;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");session.setPassword(JaspytPasswordEncryptor.getDecryptedString(jaspytEncryptionKey, jaspytEncryptionAlgorithm, password));

        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        channelSftp.cd(path);

        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls("*.csv");
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
            if (entry.getFilename().startsWith("A...")) {
                findByFileName(entry.getFilename());
            }
        }
        channelSftp.exit();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        LOGGER.error("JSch exception"+e);
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Sftp Exception"+e);
    }
}
```

Test class so far:

```
@Test
public void getNamesTestValid() throws IOException, JSchException { 
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch.setConfig(config);

    Session session = jsch.getSession( "remote-username", "localhost", 22999);
    session.setPassword("remote-password");

    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
    channel.connect();

    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        Mockito.when(fileRepository.findByFileName(fileName)).thenReturn(fileDetail);
    scheduler.getCSVFileNames();    
}
```

When trying to mock the connection, it searches for the actual port and the error is port invalid, connection refused.
I only want to mock the connection.
My other doubt is after mocking the connection from where should i read the file details.

Comment: You said you are mocking the connection in the test but your code seems not?

`Session session = jsch.getSession( "remote-username", "localhost", 22999);
        session.setPassword("remote-password");

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
        channel.connect();`

Comment: To your second question, you don't read the fileDetails from the test by calling :
`Mockito.when(fileRepository.findByFileName(fileName)).thenReturn(fileDetail);`

This mock the class to be tested, when the class call fileRepository.findByFileName, and mock the response for the caller method, which i assume is `findByFileName(entry.getFilename());` in getFile(). However, your actual class does nothing to the response to findByFileName().

Comment: Instead of mocking the connection, which might not test the actual SSH/SFTP interaction, you can also use a [fake SSH/SFTP implementation](https://github.com/shamsoftware/sham-ssh/blob/master/src/test/java/software/sham/sftp/FunctionalTest.java) that you can feed with a local temporary directory to read files from or write files to

Comment: You could also use some test docker framework (e.g. Testcontainers) and run a full-blown dockerized SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're creating an actual connection with `new Jsch()`. You need to mock the connection with a library such as `Mockito`. For example:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class Test {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private JSch mockJsch;

    ..

    void test() {
        Session mockSession = mockJsch.getSession("username", "localhost", 22999);
        ..
    }
}
```